# Finding AVG of multiple rows and displaying highest AVG

Tags: sql, database

*"display   only    the top 2   buildings   and their   corresponding   average 
price   of  a   session."*

Any help is greatly appreciated, I've been trying for ages this is my best attempt (I think) so far...

```
SELECT BUILDINGNO.BUILDING, AVG(SESSIONPRICE.CONFERENCESESSION)
FROM BUILDING
JOIN CONFERENCESESSION ON BUILDINGNO.BUILDING = BUILDINGNO.CONFERENCESESSION
WHERE BUILDINGNO.BUILDING = SESSIONPRICE.CONFERENCESESSION
GROUP BY BUILDINGNO.BUILDING
Order by BUILDINGNO.BUILDING DESC;
```

Cheers

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: If any of the answers below became helpful to you or solved your problem, kindly upvote and/or accept the answer. That'll be helpful for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
SELECT TOP 2  BUILDINGNO.BUILDING, AVG(SESSIONPRICE.CONFERENCESESSION)
FROM BUILDING
JOIN CONFERENCESESSION ON BUILDINGNO.BUILDING = BUILDINGNO.CONFERENCESESSION
WHERE BUILDINGNO.BUILDING = SESSIONPRICE.CONFERENCESESSION
GROUP BY BUILDINGNO.BUILDING
Order by AVG(SESSIONPRICE.CONFERENCESESSION) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use row number/limit.. depends on the database you use

```
SELECT BUILDINGNO.BUILDING, AVG(SESSIONPRICE.CONFERENCESESSION)
FROM BUILDING
JOIN CONFERENCESESSION ON BUILDINGNO.BUILDING = 
        BUILDINGNO.CONFERENCESESSION
WHERE BUILDINGNO.BUILDING = SESSIONPRICE.CONFERENCESESSION
   AND rownum <3 /*if you are using oracle */
GROUP BY BUILDINGNO.BUILDING
Order by BUILDINGNO.BUILDING DESC;
```

Comment: I just copied from your query. CONFERENCESESSION is a column in table buildingno? Is building a table?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the problem I must know which **database** are you using. For i.e. if you are using **oracle** than `Rownum` and `Rowcount` should solve the problem.If you are using **sql server**, you should use `TOP`.

I'll give the solution for Mysql:

```
SELECT BUILDINGNO.BUILDING, AVG(SESSIONPRICE.CONFERENCESESSION)
FROM BUILDING
JOIN CONFERENCESESSION ON BUILDINGNO.BUILDING = BUILDINGNO.CONFERENCESESSION
WHERE BUILDINGNO.BUILDING = SESSIONPRICE.CONFERENCESESSION
GROUP BY BUILDINGNO.BUILDING
Order by AVG(SESSIONPRICE.CONFERENCESESSION) DESC
limit 2;
```

For the oracle and sql server, you can follow the answer of @Valli & @sarslan respectively.

Hope it helps!